# Spring JPA Repository Cannot Catch EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to throw a custom error class when a user searches my repo with an invalid ID.  This should be very straight forward, but I cannot seem to catch any errors thrown by JpaRepository.  I have made several attempts to solve this, but the following is my most straight forward attempt:

```
try {
    Object obj = repository.getOne(id)
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
    throw CustomException("message");
}
```

When running this in a debugger, repository throws the exact exception I am expecting `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`, but the code simply skips over my catch statement and the function returns with an error.

I tried using `repository.findById(id)` with similar results.  I also tried catching `Exception` and `Throwable`.  Any ideas?  I will add more information to my post if it ends up my problem is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! I'm not getting why it behaves like that, why it skips the catch :(

Answer (score 13):

`getOne()` is just a wrapper for `EntityManager.getReference()`. That method will not throw any exception.

It returns an uninitialized proxy, **assuming** that the entity indeed exists. It doesn't get the entity state from the database, and thus doesn't even know if it exists. It assumes it does.

You'll only get an exception later, if you try to access the state of the entity.

Use `findById()`/`findOne()`, check if you get a non-empty/non-null result (because these methods don't throw any exception if the entity doesn't exist, they return empty or null), and throw your exception if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
try {
    Object obj = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
}
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
    throw CustomException("message");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since @JB Nizet already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your repository class with @Repository annotation to perform wrapping of exceptions to specific persistence exceptions.

What regarding question - you don't need to use getOne() with potential exception, but could use some other methods without throwing errors in case if entity not present, like findById() or another one that return Optional<> object

Comment: This was correct.  I had to wrap my response with an Optional<>.  Counter-intuitive to a C++ guy.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can catch `DataAccessException` instead of `EntityNotFoundException`

```
try {
    Object obj = repository.getOne(id)
}
catch (DataAccessException e) {
    throw CustomException("message");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Check @JB Nizet's answer. `getOne(id)` does not immediately throw any exception when entity is not found.